# Why is Nexus 3 using blobstore?

Tags: nexus3

I can't understand nor find the reason why Sonatype Nexus switched from regular file system to blobstore to store the artifacts between version 2 and 3.

Does anyone know why they made this choice and what it improves?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to address your question directly to them. The only thing I found out is their [FAQ](http://blog.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-3.0-qa) where they say additional metadata can be retrieved from Orient database in combination with data stored in blobstores.